# Send var from PHP to JS with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

The answer witch had been linked is 9 years old and i don't think that this is uptodate.
I try to send a var from a PHP scrit to a js scrip with Ajax but i am not sure that this is working and so i have tried to have it in the console log but i get this error :
[image: Error log]

My php script is as following :

```
<?php
$var = "Mountain";
echo json_encode($var);
echo $var;
?>

<div id="Window">
<script 
src="TestAjax9.js">
</script>
```

and the script TestAjax9.js is as following :

```
var requete = new XMLHttpRequest();
requete.onload = function() {
 //La variable à passer est alors contenue dans l'objet response et l'attribut responseText.
 var variableARecuperee = this.responseText;
};
requete.open("get", "line_chart V14.php", false); //True pour que l'exécution du script continue pendant le chargement, false pour attendre.
requete.send();
console.log("AU",variableARecuperee);
```

Comment: I have edited my post but i don't see the comments and don't understand why my post is still closed ?